# Reducing confidence intervals and alpha into a single confidence measure for layperson?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, sample

Is there a statistical approach or other practical convention for converting the statistical outputs into a single measure of 'confidence' in an estimate that a layperson can easily interpret?

#### Example

Suppose we observe a binomial event occur with outcomes: `0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0`. A good example could be whether a customer read a newsletter sent to them (we may try to estimate whether they will read a future newsletter sent to them) based on their history of reading / not reading emails

We can say (in R code)

```
# Sample of whether customer read email in the past (9 previous emails sent)
logical_sample <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0) # 0 = did not read; 1 = did read

sample_mean <- mean(logical_sample) # 0.4444444
sample_st_deviation <- sd(logical_sample) # 0.5270463
n <- length(logical_sample) # 9
alpha <- 0.95 

confidence_interval <- function(alpha, sample_mean, sample_st_deviation) {
  qnorm(1-(1-alpha)/2) * (sample_st_deviation / sqrt(n)) # note: qnorm(0.975)# [1] 1.959964
}

confidence_interval(alpha, sample_mean, sample_st_deviation) # 0.3443306
```

Now suppose a non-technical person does not want to know these statistics, but instead wants to know only two things, 1. the expected outcome, and 2. "how confident we are as a percent". E.g. 10% might be a fairly wild guess, 50% might be a little confident, 90% would be quite confident etc.

The first is straight forward `0.444`, but for the second..

We can say the event that we witnessed 9 (`n`) times, has an expected outcome of `0.444` and that we are 95% confident that the mean is within `0.444` +/- `0.344` (i.e. between `0.10` and `0.789`)

How can we map these stats to a 'confidence' percentage (that a layperson could use to gauge how confident we are of the estimate)

#### Question

How can we map these statistics into a single figure that the ***layperson*** describes as 'confidence'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a direct answer to this, so this is certainly not an answer. But here is something to think about:

**CI as interval of acceptable hypothetical values.** Consider the one-sample t test of $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_a: \mu \ne \mu_0.$ One fails to reject (let's just say "Accepts") $H_0$ at the 5% level if $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ lies in the interval between $\pm t^*,$ where $t^*$ cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail of Student's t dist'n with $df = n-1.$

"Inverting the test," one has the 95% confidence interval (CI) $\bar X \pm t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}.$ Thus, in effect, the 95% CI is the set of "Acceptable" values $\mu_0.$

**Approximate binomial test.** In your binomial example, the test of $H_0: p = p_0$ against $H_a: p \ne p_0,$ is often Accepted at the 5% level if 
$Z = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}$ has $|Z| < 1.96,$ where $\hat p = x/n$ (the proportion of Successes in $n$ trials) and 1.96 cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail of the standard normal distribution.  This is not an exact test because it relies on a normal approximation to the binomial.

**Wald interval is asymptotic, not for small samples.** Furthermore, the Wald CI for $p$ does not even try to "invert" the approximate test. The CI is of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{{\hat p(1-\hat p)}/{n}}.$ This introduces a second approximation, estimating
the standard error $\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}$ by $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$
The normal approximation together with the estimation of the standard
error can go badly wrong for small $n$ and $p_0$ far from 1/2. The result
can be a so-called "95%" confidence interval with *much* less than 95% probability
of including the true value of $p.$ (Perhaps see graphs [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375887/questions-on-issues-with-using-frequentist-and-bayesian-approach-for-the-same-te/378606#378606).)

**Wilson CI leads to Agresti CI** It is possible, but messy to find and solve an appropriate quadratic equation to invert the normal test. The messy result is the [Wilson CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval_with_continuity_correction) shown on Wikipedia. The Agresti-Coull CI ignores small terms in the Wilson formula, conflates
1.96 with 2, and simplifies the algebra.

**Approximate duality of binomial test and CI.** Thus, up to normal approximation and Agresti-Coull simplification, one can say that a 95% A-C CI consists of "Acceptable" values of $p_0$ in the test of $H_0.$ This is "pretty much" true if the normal approximation is valid.
(Some authors give the rule of thumb that $\min(np_0, n(1-p_0) > 5$ for that.)